# problem with pasting data from one palce to a text box on the same webpage

Tags: automation, textarea

I am currently trying to write a code that takes specific data from a webpage and paste it in a text area on the same page, but the problem is all the text the code paste is not saved until I press on the keyboard like Enter key or any other character.

Comment: please add screenshot and code here to help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.